# Given point in triangle, prove that it is the centroid

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, centroid

So the question goes like this:

Given a triangle ABC, there is a point M within that triangle such that [AMB]=[AMC]=[BMC]. Prove that M is the centroid of the triangle. ([AMC] denotes the area of triangle AMC)

I can easily prove the converse, that if M is the centroid, then the areas are equal, but I don't know how to prove this. 
Can anyone help me? I have tried placing the triangle in a coordinate system, among other things, but could not get anywhere.

Comment: If we know that $M_c$ is the centroid of the triangle $\Delta ABC$, then $M_c$ divides the triangle into 3 equal areas. Can it happen that $M\not=M_c$ but we again have a division into 3 equal areas?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to prove that the centroid is the only point where this can occur. This could be a proof by contradiction, but I have no idea how to get to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\triangle MBC$ has one-third the area of $\triangle ABC$, yet has the same "base", $\overline{BC}$, it follows that $M$'s distance to that base is one-third $A$'s distance; therefore: $M$ is on the line, parallel to $\overline{BC}$, through the "lower" trisection point of the altitude from $A$. Likewise, $M$ is on lines parallel to $\overline{CA}$ and $\overline{AB}$ through corresponding trisection points on the altitudes from $B$ and $C$. We know that the three lines have the centroid in common, and that (because they are distinct) they can share no other point. Therefore, any "area-trisecting point" $M$ must coincide with the centroid itself. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

If the comment was not helpful enough: suppose we know that the centroid divides the triangle into 3 triangles of equal area.

Given $M$ and $M_c$, the point in question and the centroid respectively, we have that:
$$[AMC]+[AMB]+[BMC]={\text Area}(\Delta ABC)=[AM_cC]+[AM_cB]+[BM_cC]$$ 
Now, letting the heights of the triangles corresponding to $M$ be 
$$h_{AC}, h_{AB},h_{BC}$$
and the heights of the triangles corresponding to $M_c$ be 
$$H_{AC}, H_{AB},H_{BC}$$
we have the following:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\overline{AC}\cdot h_{AC}+\overline{AB}\cdot h_{AB}+\overline{BC}\cdot h_{BC} \right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\overline{AC}\cdot H_{AC}+\overline{AB}\cdot H_{AB}+\overline{BC}\cdot H_{BC} \right)$$
From here, can you deduce that the points $M_c$ and $M$ are equal?

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be any point inside $\triangle ABC$ such that $[ABP] = [APC]$, then

$$|AB||AP|\sin(\angle PAB) = 2[ABP] = 2[APC] = |AP||AC|\sin(\angle CAP)\\
\implies \sin(\angle CAP) : \sin(\angle PAB) = |AB| : |AC|
$$
Since $\angle CAP + \angle PAB = \angle CAB$ is independent of choice of $P$,
the last equality forces $\angle CAP$ and $\angle PAB$ to be independent of choice of $P$.  This means the locus of any point $P$ which satifies the condition $[ABP] = [ABC]$ lies on a line passing through $A$. It is easy to see this line passes through the mid-point of $BC$ too. This tells us the locus is the median of $\triangle ABC$ through $A$.

If you don't want to use trigonometric fucntions, you can extend the line $AP$ and let it hit $BC$ at $X$. It is easy to see

$$\begin{align}
& [ABX] : [ABP] = |AX| : |AP| = [AXC] : [APC]\\
\implies &
|AX| : |XC| = [ABX] : [AXC] = [ABP] : [APC] = 1 : 1
\end{align}$$
From this, we can conclude $X$ is the mid-point of $BC$ and once again, $P$ lies on
the median $AX$ of $\triangle ABC$.

Back to original problem. If a point $M$ satisfies $[AMB] = [BMC] = [CMA]$, then $M$ lies on the intersection of the three medians of $\triangle ABC$. By definition, $M$ will be the centroid of the triangle.

Comment: Okay, I think I almost understand. But in the first part of your answer you say that it is easy to see that the line AP passes through the mid-point of BC. Sadly, I do not see this. How is this true?

Comment: @Cataline, this is because $|BX| = |XC| \implies [ABX] = [AXC]$, so $X$ is a possible candidate of $P$.